# set ansi_warnings off not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

Why do I still receiving in the emails: `Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.` If I have set the `ansi_warnings off`

```
set ansi_warnings off   

        set @subj = 'xxx'
        set @msg = 'xxx' + char(13) + char(10) 
        set @q = 'select LSRNbr, trh.ShipperId, InvoiceNbr, Qty, count(LotSerNbr) as QtyRcvd
                from tblRIM2_Header trh (nolock)
                left outer join tblRIM2_SerialsFromFile trs (nolock) on trh.ShipperId = trs.ShipperId
                where isnull(Completed,0) = 0 
                group by trh.ShipperId, LSRNbr, InvoiceNbr, Qty'

        exec master.dbo.xp_sendmail 
          @recipients = 'xxx',            
          @subject = @subj , 
          @query = @q, 
          @message = @msg, 
          @attach_results = FALSE, 
          @dbuse = 'GlobalQCS'

        set ansi_warnings on
```

Comment: Maybe you have to put `set ansi_warnings off` inside `@q` ?

Comment: Finally!!! :) please place an answer to give u the credit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put `set ansi_warnings off` inside `@q`:

```
set @q = 'set ansi_warnings off select LSRNbr, trh.ShipperId, ...`
```